# Define golang struct as type with arbitrary fields?

Tags: go, struct, interface

I'm very new to golang and the use of interfaces more generally. I've stubbed out some code here:

```
type Alerter interface {
    Alert()
}

type AlertConfig struct{}

type Alert struct {
    Config *AlertConfig
}

type AlertConfigurator interface {
    UpdateConfig(key, value interface{}) (*AlertConfig, error)
}

type EmailAlertConfig AlertConfig {
    Recipients []mail.Address,
}

type HTTPAlertConfig AlertConfig {
    Method string
    TargetURL url.URL
}

type HTTPAlert struct {
    Config *HTTPAlertConfig
}

type EmailAlert struct {
    Config *EmailAlertConfig
}

func (ea *EmailAlert) Alert() {
    // this would actually send an email using data in its Config
    return
}

func (ha *HTTPAlert) Alert() {
    // this would actually hit an HTTP endpoint using data in its Config
    return
}
```

I'm sure I have all kinds of assumptions & biases that are hobbling my ability to express what I want to accomplish with this:

I want to create different types of "Alert"s. Any alert I create should have an "Alert()"
method that triggers the Alert to actually do something (send an email, or POST to a URL,
for example.

The trouble comes in representing an Alert's "Config". Different Alerts have different fields
in their Configs. However, for each Alert type, *specific* fields *are* required to be there.
To accomplish that I wanted to create a base type "AlertConfig" as a struct with arbitrary fields,
then define, say, `EmailAlertConfig` as type 'AlertConfig', but having these specific fields, and then
type 'HTTPAlertConfig' as type 'AlertConfig' requiring different fields. This way, I can define
the 'Alert' type as having a field 'Config *AlertConfig'.

I can almost emulate what I want if AlertConfig is defined as map[string]interface{}, but
in this case I can't leverage golang's checking to validate that an EmailConfig has the required fields.

It seems pretty clear that I'm thinking about this the wrong way. I could use a hand in getting on the right track & appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a type with the common fields:

```
 type AlertConfig struct { 
    ExampleCommonField string
 }
```

[Embed](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding) that type in actual configurations:

```
type HTTPAlertConfig struct {
    AlertConfig
    Method string
    TargetURL url.URL
}
```

Based on the code in the question, the alert and config types can be combined.

```
func (ha *HTTPAlertConfig) Alert() {
    // this will hit an HTTP endpoint using data in the receiver
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with this problem is to leave configs as purely implementation specific:

```
type HTTPAlert struct {
  Config *HTTPAlertConfig
}

func (a *HTTPAlert) Alert() {...}

type EmailAlert struct {
  Config *EmailAlertConfig
}

func (e *EmailAlert) Alert() {...}
```

With this implementation, the actual `Alert` implementation can use the type-specific alert configuration, leaving the problem of initializing the config.

When you create the instance of an alert, you can perform type-specific initialization. For instance:

```
var alerts = map[string]func(configFile string) Alert {
   "htmlAlert": NewHTMLAlert,
   "emailAlert" NewEmailAlert,
}

func NewHTMLAlert(configFile string) Alert {
  var alert HTMLAlert
  // Read file, initialize alert
  return &alert
}
...
```